# RecyclerView Last item visible after deleting it from RecylerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview) in my application. Using Interface in `Adapter` class I am deleting the items from `Recyclerview`.But when last item is deleted, it is still visible in RecyclerView.After manually again calling the same `Fragment` it get removed.This is code from `Adapter` class to call delete method

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
        private  TextView number;
        private  TextView people;
        private TextView myDate;
        private TextView myTime;
        private TextView myNumber;
        private TextView reservationId;
        private TextView foodieId;
        private ImageView deleteReservation;
        private ImageView editReservation;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView, final OnEntryClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            number=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            deleteEntry=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            editReservation=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editReservation);
            deleteEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener!=null) {
                        int position = originalList.indexOf(filter.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.deleteEntry(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });        
        }
    }
```

This is code for deleting item in `Recyclerview` class where it is displayed.

```
@Override
                                public void deleteEntry(final int position) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    confirm.setTitle("Confirmation");
                                    confirm.setMessage("Are you sure to cancel reservation ?");
                                    confirm.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                                                            removeItem(position);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    confirm.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            alertDialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    confirm.show();
                                }
```

This is method to delete item

```
public void removeItem(int position) {

                current.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, current.size()-1);

            }
```

What should be the change to remove the last item which is visible after deleting also ?

Comment: what is current.remove?

Comment: its my arrayList

Comment: @Stayam you can try calling NotifyItemchanged only.

Comment: You have 3 arrayList, `current`, `originalList` & `filter`. Perhaps you are not managing correct position .

Comment: recyclerview notifydatasetchange won't work. if you setadapter twice. coz it loses it's reference. Please check that

Comment: current is the final list which is displayed on Fragment. Original and filter is in adapter for filtering logic

Comment: You should remove from original list also.

Comment: I have done this still not working

Comment: You should debug code and test it where is object is left after removing the item otherwise you should post whole adapter as well

Comment: Why don't you use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789345/whats-better-notifydatasetchanged-or-notifyitemchanged-in-loop) question for more info. I always use it in my recyclerviews they all update with no issues. Also I usually set my click listeners in my bindViewHolder but that's up to you of course.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `current.size()-1` by current.size() like this:

```
//case size == 1
current.remove(position);

//size == 0 here
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

//just call current.size()
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, current.size());
```

Comment: did you check that you got the correct item position inside removeItem()?

Comment: Yes.its 0 position.

Answer (score 0):

Also item remove from arraylist like this

```
 public void deleteEntry(final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    confirm.setTitle("Confirmation");
    confirm.setMessage("Are you sure to cancel reservation ?");
    confirm.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            current.remove(position);
            yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    confirm.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    confirm.show();
}
```

Comment: if item deleted in such a way what should be the methods in removeItem(position)

Comment: @satyam its works only if arraylist value change without change inside method not work

Answer (score 0):

```
                               public void deleteEntry(final int position) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                confirm.setTitle("Confirmation");
                                confirm.setMessage("Are you sure to cancel reservation ?");
                                confirm.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                      current.remove(position);
                                      notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }
                                });
                                confirm.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        alertDialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                                confirm.show();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
        int position = myMatches.indexOf(r);
        if (position > -1) {
            your_list.remove(position);

            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
```