# How to update just one View in a particular item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with 10 items.
Every item has a **TextView** and an **ImageView**.

Let us suppose for item 5, I just want to update the TextView and leave its ImageView as t is, how can we proceed to do it?

I can use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` but it will try to refresh the entire layout, which I don't want. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can proceed to use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` because it is actually just update the item at the given position

I saw someone explaining about item and structural changes in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33792079), which state that `notifyItemChanged(int position)` is actually just change the given item position, rather than `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will redraw everything

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logic in onBindViewHolder to just update the TextView:

> ```
>     if (onlyTextViewNeedsUpdate)
>         // Update TextView
>     else
>         // Update all views
> ```