# Is there any way make Android RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged but don't call onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I make a recyclerView and update dataset with `notifyDataSetChanged`
and it will call `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`

Is there any way just call `onBindViewHolder` but don't call `onCreateViewHolder` after `notifyDataSetChanged`?
Because i want to save some states in viewholder but still want to update view.

I try to use `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)` but not works.

```
class SelectionAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var selectionList = mutableListOf<BetSelection>()

    fun setData(selectionList: List<BetSelection>) {
        this.selectionList = selectionList.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        
            val viewBinding = SelectionItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
            val viewHolder = SelectionViewHolder(viewBinding, parent.context)
            viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)
            return viewHolder
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
      when (holder) {
            is SelectionViewHolder -> {
                holder.setSelection(selectionList[position])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = selectionList.count()
}
```

```
class SelectionViewHolder(
    private val viewBinding: SelectionItemBinding,
    private val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root) {

    private var isOddsInitComplete = false

    fun setSelection(selection: Selection) {

    //isOddsInitComplete always false because onCreateViewHolder called everytime
    if(isOddsInitComplete) {
        updateOdds()
    } else {
        initOddsView()
        isOddsInitComplete = true
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: You can use [`notifyItemChanged()` or `notifyItemRangeChanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789345/whats-better-notifydatasetchanged-or-notifyitemchanged-in-loop)

Comment: @Nitish Thank for comments, but i want to update all holders.

Comment: i think you want t update all data but you dont want animation wile recyclerView do when we notified data changed

Comment: What exactly are you trying to save in the ViewHolder? Could you store that data elsewhere (e.g. in a list in the adapter) and look them up by position instead? I don't think the ViewHolder is really intended for storing things other than interchangeable views

Comment: @TylerV I edit my question, i want to save a boolean in viewholder that decides  what i need to do

Comment: So could you just save a list of booleans in the adapter and then access that using the position instead?

Comment: @TylerV yes I can. So there is no way to cancel onCreatViewViewHolde after notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Not that I know of - and I'm not sure you would want to, I don't think there is any guarantee that a holder gets bound to the same spot in the list.