# How to swap the selected recycler view item with the first item with change background color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-adapter

[image]here I change the background of the selected item position and set that item to the first position init

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FeelingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.title.text = context.resources.getString(item.stringResourceId)
        holder.emoji.setImageResource(item.imageResourceId)

        holder.emoji.setOnClickListener {
            selectedItemPos = position

            notifyItemMoved(position, 0)
        }

        if (selectedItemPos == position)         

holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#200f726b"))
        else
          holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
}
```

I tried different ways but I failed

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

According to your updated question, you must write something like this:

```
if (position == 0)
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#200f726b"))
```

Let me know if it didn't work

**Original answer:**

First, you'd better use notifyItemMoved(position,0) instead of notifyDataSetChanged() because it has less performance overhead. You can read about the reason here:

[What's better? notifyDataSetChanged or notifyItemChanged in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789345/whats-better-notifydatasetchanged-or-notifyitemchanged-in-loop?answertab=trending#tab-top)

if "selectedItemPos" is out of onBind method, the item that has recently been in the first position should be colorful

Comment: Thanks, Hamed Gord but it's not working. I'm sharing my adapter code... please check

Comment: I updated my adapter code please have a look.

Comment: I think this code makes the first item that has been moved to a new position colorful. Is your output anything else? then pls share your current output and your expectation

Comment: check again the question I updated with a pic... so, this is my recycler view and I set multiple emojis and text. I want when I click on the sad emoji... sad emoji to move to the first position and change the background...  I try when I click any item moves to the first position and change that item's background...

Comment: Someone please help... I wanna fix this today's only

Comment: I've solved you question after update